# Closed form solution for integral involving inverse Mills ratio?

Tags: normal-distribution, integral

Is there a closed form solution for the integral
$$\int_0^a \sqrt{c} \phi\left(\frac{\mu}{\sigma}\sqrt{c}\right) m e^{-mc} dc$$
where $\phi(x)$ is the standard normal pdf? If it exists what is it?

I've checked here and couldn't find anything that helps:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrals_of_Gaussian_functions

Comment: The problem sounds quite peculiar, with $\mu/\sigma$ of no relevance (by a change of scale) and the $-$ in the Normal density (pdf) of no use at all, since it is symmetric. The integral would be easier to compute if $1/\sqrt{c}$ was to be used instead of $\sqrt c$ at the beginning.

Comment: This is part of an expression derived from a model, and the distinction between those parameters is relevant for other terms which I omitted. But you're right that it does not matter for this purpose (neither does the minus in the pdf). Any hope?

Comment: Edited to ask about a simpler case which would also help.

Comment: Please keep simplifying -- it should lead you easily to a multiple of the incomplete Gamma function with parameter $3/2.$